# How could/should I print text strings above number columns in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

I would like to print the strings at the top of columns with a 1 x 3 array.

I have edited this simple function several times, and this produces the least errors. New to C++, reading Deital Chap 6 Recursive.

What am I missing? I started with half brackes around strings, and brackets seemed to produce less errors.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {

array a[1][3] = ["Car" "Hours" "Charge"]

cout<< a << endl;
}
```

Terminal produces errors as such:

```
parking_charges_6_12.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
parking_charges_6_12.cpp:8:7: error: missing template arguments before ‘a’
    8 | array a[1][3] = ["Car" "Hours" "Charge"]
              ^
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples at the bottom of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). In C++ you can either use the old C-style arrays or `std::array`. Your code looks like it is half way between the two, which does not work.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::array<std::string, 3> headlines = {"Car", "Hours", "Charge"};
  for( auto const& elem : headlines ){
    std::cout << elem << "\t";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be curly braces `{}` in the initializer, not `[]`. And you need a comma between each element.

On the other hand, in later C++ revisions `array` can detect the type and number of elements, so you don't have to give that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   array a = {"Car", "Hours", "Charge"};

   for (auto& item : a)
      cout<< item << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   string data[3] = {"Car", "Hours", "Charge"};
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      cout << data[i] << " ";
}
```

Obviously it is not using the array header, but it's a working example. If you do need to use the array header, you can try something like :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  
int main() {
  array<string, 3> ar3 = {"Car", "Hours", "Charge"};
 
  cout << ar3.size() << endl;
    
  for (auto i : ar3)
    cout << i << ' ';
 return 0;
}
```

You can see it working online [here](https://www.online-cpp.com/DecJKt3puf)

Comment: The code in the question looks like you were supposed to use `std::array`

Comment: Also why are you using an array with 4 elements?

Comment: @JakobStark simple typo my friend

Comment: @eike Was adding two solutions, just posted the first part earlier

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail you should post an answer only when is fully complete. No need to play [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731).

Comment: @justANewbie Will keep it in mind, thanks for the link :)